# One rewrite rule or multiple ones in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a main domain, a couple of addon domains and recently went HTTPS. This is working OK for me but I would like your opinion:

```
## All http requests to the relative https url
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
## redirect the other domains and the non www main main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain3.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain3.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain2.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain.com
## this stuff is for SSL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
## i send them all to the https main domain
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.maindomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Is this a better approach to having a rewrite rule for each condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There certainly isn't a need for multiple `RewriteRule` directives. That would only complicate things and be less efficient. If you have multiple rules (for each condition) then each rule would at least be processed, even if you were already at the canonical protocol + host.

However, you seem to be redirecting *every* other domain. Everything that is *not* `www.maindomain.com`. If this is the case then you can simplify this rule and do away with the multiple *conditions*. For example:

```
## All http requests to the relative https url
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
## redirect all the other non-canonical domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.maindomain\.com
## this stuff is for SSL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
## i send them all to the https main domain
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.maindomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

So, this now says... if HTTP or not `www.maindomain.com` then redirect to HTTPS and `www.maindomain.com`. Instead of specifically checking for every non-canonical host, you are just checking to see that it is not the canonical host.

No need for the start and end anchors if you are capturing the entire URL-path anyway. ie. `(.*)` is the same as `^(.*)$`.

Or, you could avoid the regex *capturing* and just use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead (which notably starts with a slash). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^ https://www.maindomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

> ```
> ## this stuff is for SSL
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
> ```

This looks like the carbuncle that cPanel (automatically) injects before *every* `RewriteRule` when renewing SSL certs. If you have a lot of `RewriteRule` directives in `.htaccess` this makes for an incredibly bloated `.htaccess` file. (It can also expose vulnerabilities that were not evident previously.) I don't know why they don't separate these conditions into a single block at the start of the file and negate (ie. invert) them instead? For example:

```
# START: this stuff is for SSL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# END: this stuff is for SSL

## All http requests to the relative https url
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
## redirect all the other non-canonical domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.maindomain\.com
## i send them all to the https main domain
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.maindomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Cool! thanks for that explanation, tho testing it, it do not redirect the canonical versions of the other domains, well the other domains are just to  protect the name, are domain.net, domain.org that point to .com

Comment: Hhhmmm, it should "redirect the canonical versions of the other domains", providing they are all pointing to the same place on the filesystem? Basically, any request that is _not_ for `www.maindomain.com` should be redirected. Note the `!` at the start of the _CondPattern_. Make sure the browser cache is cleared as any erroneous 301 redirect gets cached hard by the browser.

Comment: Yep, it redirect the non canonical version of the others ones, it just not redirect the canonical ones, i mean it redirect domain1.com to www.maindoimain.com but if you use www.domain1.com it remain there i will clean and test